# How do I keep obstacles from spawning on top of each other?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, monogame

I'll keep this quick - how do I get obstacles (like the cacti in chrome dino) to spawn always with a gap big enough for the player to actually fit between two obstacles?
They're just slapping themselves at any time, and I can't even land between some of them.

```
Random random = new Random();
private int amount;

private int ob1X = 600;
private int viewportWidth = 600;


protected override void LoadContent()
{
    amount = random.Next(0, 3);
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (amount == 0)
    {
        ob1X--;
        if (ob1X + 10 <= 0)
        {
            ob1X = viewportWidth;
            amount = random.Next(0, 3);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is everything relating to my obstacles, and the rest is as expected - if amount == 1, do the same thing with the second obstacle and so on.
This my first game, so please don't judge if this is an awful way of doing things, though I'll take any clear advice on how to make a better random obstacle generator.

I'm using a MonoGame template.

Thank you! :)

Comment: To answer this, we'll need to know how you spawn your obstacles currently